# Java list intersection in lambda and collect pair

Tags: java

I have two lists. The insertion order into the "idOrderList" is also the sort order needed for the "idAndIndexList". I'm intersecting the list as below in the code.

```
{
    List<String> idOrderList; //insertion order in this list is sort order
    List<Pair<String,Integer>> idAndIndexList; 
    //List intersection is done as below
    List resultList = 
        idOrderList.stream().filter(
            new HashSet<>(idAndIndexList.stream()
            .flatMap(o -> Stream.of(o.getLeft(),o.getRight()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList()))::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

I'm stuck at how to collect the "Pair.getRight()" into the "resultList" or alternately I want to collect the "idAndIndexList" Pair as result but maintain the insertion order of "idOrderList". 
Any input or suggestions. Many Thanks in advance

- GS

Comment: Just because streams are available they are not necessarily the best choice to solve every collection related problem. Just use a simple for-loop and your done.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach is to convert `idAndIndexList` into its corresponding `right` value set and use `Set.contains`. This also avoids running the `idAndIndexList.stream()` pipeline multiple times unnecessarily:

```
Set<String> idSet = idAndIndexList.stream()
            .map(Pair::getLeft)
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());

List<String> resultList = idOrderList.stream()
        .filter(idSet::contains)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

> ...alternately I want to collect the "idAndIndexList" Pair as result but maintain the insertion order of "idOrderList"

Regarding this approach, you can use `sorted` and sort items based on their index in `idOrderList`:

```
List<String> resultList2 = idAndIndexList.stream()
        .map(Pair::getLeft)
        .sorted(Comparator.comparingInt(idOrderList::indexOf)) //be careful here
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it's important to note that if `idAndIndexList` contains duplicates, the result may be something other than what you'd expect. The first approach is more reliable in this case.